# To retrieve deleted Gmail mails

Tags: gmail, data-recovery

Every six months I used to delete the mails in my inbox but now I need access to one of the emails I deleted a year back.

Is there any way to recover the mail?

Comment: You are aware that if there is a chance you need an email the proper action is archive not delete?

Answer (score 1):

Any email you delete goes to your Trash. Just go to Trash just below Spam on the left vertical menu. However, you you have emptied your Trash, then it now depends on Gmail.

If Gmail has not deleted the messages from the server, you can recover deleted emails after deleting them from your trash folder. You must open your gmail then click the drop down arrow on the left from your search box at the top of the screen. it will then ask you several question such as to: or from, subject, key words or date within. Click on the blue search button on the bottom left of the search box and all of your deleted emails will be revealed. http://www.itpro.co.uk/email-clients/26076/how-to-recover-deleted-emails-in-gmail-2.

Gmail Help link:https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7015314?hl=en&visit_id=1-636441828911162408-3017547055&rd=1

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly which email you need, the easiest option to get a fresh copy is to contact the sender and ask for that email to be resent/forwarded to you. It's unlikely you'll be able to get Google to restore a single email from their backup archives.

The other question is whether you've downloaded the email to one of your computers (e.g., Outlook, Mail, Thunderbird, or another client). If so, that's an option for you to obtain the email (or restore from backup).